# Why is mysql_error() used?

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner in php and I am making a form and pass the values to database using php. Also  I am trying to check a field if it is empty or not when I press the submit button. I have read about mysql_error(), but I dont understand exactly what it does. So can anyone explain me which is the difference between the lines below:

```
if(empty($_POST['fname']))
die ('Name is empty </body></html>');
```

and

```
if(empty($_POST['fname']))
die ('Name is empty'. mysql_error().'</body></html>');
```

When I press the submit button in both cases I have the same result...Only the message: Name is empty. So which is the use if mysql_error() ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say you're a *"beginner in php"* so why is it you've ignored the [**big red warning**](http://php.net/mysql_error)? I would have thought a beginner would pay closer attention.

Comment: I also suggest you read this to avoid the `or die` anti-pattern - http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not executing a MySQL database call on that code. So it won't return anything. This code:

```
if(empty($_POST['fname']))
die ('Name is empty'. mysql_error().'</body></html>');
```

Uses `die` if `Name` is empty. However, `Name` has nothing to do with MySQL, even though it is being passed to MySQL, it is not directly involving it. `$_POST` variables are variables, not directly related to MySQL. If this were say a MySQL query, like:

```
$mysql = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if(!mysql)
die ('Could not connect: '. mysql_error().'</body></html>');
```

Then it would tell you that it couldn't connect and the specific error message.

Comment: Yes i have included it at mysql_connect, but I didnt know t include it when I check the name field..Or it is enough  to leave it just : die ('Name is empty </body></html>');

Comment: @user3272713 It's enough if you just want to display that name is empty. However, I would suggest against using the `or die` if this will be displayed to users. It abruptly stops the script, and doesn't really help the user too much. Instead, you could just do a `echo "Name is empty </body> </html>`.

Answer (score 1):

mysql_error() provides you with the error message if a mysql error has occured. If none has occured, it won't return anything.

More info at [the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/mysql_error).

On a sidenote, the mysql extension has been deprecated. You really should switch to using either [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).